# Boundary Behavior of Conformal maps

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a trouble with understanding the following argument.

Theorem. Let, for $R_{1}, R_{2} >1$,
$$ A_{1} =  \{ z \in \mathbb{C}: 1 < |z| < R_{1} \}, \quad A_{2} = \{ z \in \mathbb{C}: 1 < |z| < R_{2}\}.$$
Then $A_{1}$ is conformally equivalent to $A_{2}$ iff $R_{1}= R_{2}$.

In the proof of this theorem, the author argues that

> For the "only if" part, suppose $\phi: A_{1} \rightarrow A_{2}$ is a biholomorphic equivalence. If $K$ in $A_{2}$ is compact, then $\phi^{-1}(K)$ is also compact (since $\phi^{-1}$ is continuous). It follows that if a sequence $\{ w_{j} \}$ in $A_{1}$ converges to the boundary (in the obvious sense that it has no interior accumulation point), then so does the sequence $\{ \phi(w_{j}) \}$ in $A_{2}$.

I don't understand why the second sentence implies the last sentence. Also, if a sequence in $A_{1}$ has no interior accumulation point, then it actually converges to a boundary point of $A_{1}$?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: A sequence $\{w_j\}$ in $A_1$ converges to the boundary of $A_1$ if and only if for any compact $K \Subset A_1$, there exists a rank $j_K$ such that $\forall j > j_K$, $w_j \not \in K$. In other words, the sequence quits ultimately any compact of $A_1$. If $\{\phi(\omega_j)\}$ does not converge to the boundary of $A_2$, let $K$ be a compact of $A_2$ containing a subsequence of $\{\phi(\omega_j)\}$. Then $\phi^{-1}(K)$ is a compact of $A_1$ containing a subsequence of $\{\omega_j\}$ (since $\phi$ is injective).

Comment: Oh it was just a topological argument. Thank you very much.